# How to interpolate/ extrapolate in R when the vector has several NaNs?

Tags: r, interpolation, nan, spline, extrapolation

I have a vector, which contains several NaNs. For example,

*d=c(NaN,2,3,4,4,2,4,7,NaN,NaN,8,5,6,NaN)*

I would like to do some expolation to replace NaNs. The difficulty for me is that I do not know how many NaNs I have and where they are.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform linear interpolation using `zoo` functions.

```
d=c(NaN,2,3,4,4,2,4,7,NaN,NaN,8,5,6,NaN)

zoo::na.spline(d)
# [1]  1.86  2.00  3.00  4.00  4.00  2.00  4.00  7.00  9.08  9.61  8.00  5.00  6.00 15.06

zoo::na.approx(d, na.rm = FALSE)
#[1]   NA 2.00 3.00 4.00 4.00 2.00 4.00 7.00 7.33 7.67 8.00 5.00 6.00   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na_interpolation` from `imputeTS` with several option:
see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/imputeTS/versions/3.2/topics/na.interpolation

```
library(imputeTS)
na_interpolation(d, option = "linear", maxgap = Inf)
```

Output:

```
> na_interpolation(d, option = "linear", maxgap = Inf)
 [1] 2.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 4.000000 2.000000 4.000000 7.000000 7.333333 7.666667 8.000000 5.000000 6.000000
[14] 6.000000
```